# AT24C32 as a replace?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, eeprom

i want to make this part of circuit .

[image]
It uses 24AA32A IC. Can i use AT24C32 instead . im worry about A0, A1 and A2.

---

**my question :** if i want to use 24C32 , to work exactly like 24AA32 i should not connect pin A0,A1 and A2 to ground and left them NC ?

---

---

**AT24C32 Datasheet :**

[image]

---

**24AA32A Datasheet :**

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Did you compare datasheets of both devices? According to the text you’ve shown the A0-A2 pins select the I2C slave address on both devices. On the 24C32 they may be left floating, on the 24AA32 they have to be driven high or low. Since your design shows these pins to be hard wired low, this should be no problem for your 24C32.

Comment: @StarCat so if i want to use 24C32 , to work exactly like 24AA32 i should not connect pin A0,A1 and A2 to ground and left NC ?

Comment: According to the schematic you’ve shown A0-A2 should already be connected to ground if using a 24AA32. So yes, A0-A2 on the 24C32 you plan to use will work the same as the 24AA32 when hard wired to ground. In addition you may leave A0-A2 floating (unconnected) on the 24C32 which will have the same effect as connecting them to ground. I.e. they will both select the same I2C slave address on the device (50h). Read the datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chips are completely identical in addressing and protocol.

The address pins need to be connected exactly identically so no changes should be made.